# How to execute join statement dynamically without using static group id?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, cte, recursive

I work on SQL server 2014 I need to run this statement below dynamically without

using group id static

because I don't know maximum group id using may be 10,15,20

so How to run query below dynamically without write static group id on join?

```
   select r1.familyid, r1.companyid, r1.GlobalPnId,
     concat(
         r1.PortionKey,
         r2.PortionKey,
         r3.PortionKey,
         r4.PortionKey,
         r5.PortionKey,
         r6.PortionKey,
         r7.PortionKey,
         r8.PortionKey,
         r9.PortionKey
         ) as PartNumber
 from GetFinalResult r1
 left join GetFinalResult r2 on r2.familyid = r1.familyid and r2.GroupID = 2
 left join GetFinalResult r3 on r3.familyid = r1.familyid and r3.GroupID = 3
 left join GetFinalResult r4 on r4.familyid = r1.familyid and r4.GroupID = 4
 left join GetFinalResult r5 on r5.familyid = r1.familyid and r5.GroupID = 5
 left join GetFinalResult r6 on r6.familyid = r1.familyid and r6.GroupID = 6
 left join GetFinalResult r7 on r7.familyid = r1.familyid and r7.GroupID = 7
 left join GetFinalResult r8 on r8.familyid = r1.familyid and r8.GroupID = 8
 left join GetFinalResult r9 on r9.familyid = r1.familyid and r9.GroupID = 9
 where r1.GroupID = 1
```

SQL fiddle I will work on it
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d3156fd25c6fc6e673eaf299bf0a68c8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with selecting the cte into a temp table an indexing it accordingly, then replacing all the calls to cte for the temp table

You are calling the cte, which is quite complex", multiple times and it has to be evaluated every single time....

Comment: Good start, your temp table can store the results of all of the column parsing logic so that your query gets to work with "real" columns that have the correct indexes